# need libary to ocr a printed page and create tab delimited file from it

Tags: php, winapi, ocr

I am generating a pdf for a client. This has two columns ... ID and a blank column for the end user to put in some character. I want the client to be able to upload a bmp/jpg/tif whatever (i can specify) image of the printed pdf with its two columns and turn it into a csv/tab/whatever file with the values of the two columns. Can anyone recommend an ocr package that I can access from either a php web PHP or a win32 DLL that I can use from a Windows App (delphi 9)? This doesn't have to be a free package; I am willing to pay. I am aware that you can do forms in PDF and reprocess those ... that is not what I need. I need to OCR a printed document problematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [Tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)
It's C but I assume you can interact in Delphi

Comment: this looks promising! i downloaded and will check it out.